# Multiple insert with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to insert 5 llines in my db, however the following

```
$qry = $db->prepare('INSERT IGNORE INTO table (foo, bar) VALUES 
    (?,?),
    (?,?),
    (?,?),
    (?,?),
    (?,?)');
$qry->execute(array(
    array($foo1, $bar),
    array($foo2, $bar),
    array($foo3, $bar),
    array($foo4, $bar),
    array($foo5, $bar)
));
```

gives me this error

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

What should I do to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra arrays in the `execute()`

```
$qry = $db->prepare('INSERT IGNORE INTO table (foo, bar) VALUES 
    (?,?),
    (?,?),
    (?,?),
    (?,?),
    (?,?)');
$qry->execute(array(
    $foo1, $bar,
    $foo2, $bar,
    $foo3, $bar,
    $foo4, $bar,
    $foo5, $bar
));
```

Comment: Oh god... I also tried this (which gave me another error that I thought I fixed with the arrays) : `$qry->execute(array(
    ($foo1, $bar),
    ($foo2, $bar),
    ($foo3, $bar),
    ($foo4, $bar),
    ($foo5, $bar)
));`... (parenthesis added over each "$foo1, $bar" line). PHP is driving me mad. Thank you !